# Query Maximum Order Per second per day

Tags: sql

I have 1 table with this format:

```
date                    | Items
2021-07-07 00:00:00     | Shirt
2021-07-07 00:00:00     | Socks
2021-07-07 00:00:00     | Book
2021-07-07 00:00:01     | Shirt
2021-07-07 00:00:01     | Shirt
2021-07-07 00:00:03     | Shirt
2021-07-07 00:00:03     | Shirt
2021-07-07 00:00:03     | Shirt
2021-07-07 00:00:03     | Shirt
2021-07-08 00:07:01     | Shirt
2021-07-08 00:07:01     | Socks
2021-07-08 00:07:01     | Book
2021-07-08 00:07:01     | Shirt
2021-07-08 00:07:01     | Shirt
2021-07-08 00:07:01     | Shirt
2021-07-08 00:07:01     | Shirt
2021-07-08 00:07:01     | Shirt
2021-07-08 00:07:01     | Shirt
```

from above data we can see on 7 July, items:

```
shirt has highest order at 2021-07-07 00:00:03 (4 times)
book has highest order at 2021-07-07 00:00:00 (1 times)
socks has highest order at 2021-07-07 00:00:00 (1 times)
```

from above data we can see on 8 July, items:

```
shirt has highest order at 2021-07-08 00:07:01  (6 times)
book has highest order at 2021-07-08 00:07:01  (1 times)
socks has highest order at 2021-07-08 00:07:01  (1 times)
```

i want to create query to output maximum transaction per second per day. so the result will looks like this:

```
Items                   | 2021-07-07    | 2021-07-08
Shirt                   | 4             | 6
book                    | 1             | 1
socks                   | 1             | 1
```

how can i create the SQL query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What's the database you're using?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is two levels of aggregation, one by item and second and the second level only by item:

```
select item,
       max(case when cast(date as date) = '2021-07-07' then cnt end) as max_cnt_20210707,
       max(case when cast(date as date) = '2021-07-08' then cnt end) as max_cnt_20210708
from (select date, item, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      where date >= date '2021-07-07' and date < date '2021-07-09'
      group by date, item
     ) di
group by item;
```